Can I hide columns when using CloudWatch Logs Live Tail
I find the CloudWatch Logs Live Tail tool really useful but I would like to hide the log id and (optionally) the timestamp. These take up half my screen width and often are not needed. For example:
2024-11-14T10:01:11.930Z    28106ab2-426d-4cd9-aa57-e9174767f28f    INFO    Log message is here

In the above example I'm only interested in the log level and message ( I know the date - these are live logs), so for example the following would be enough:
INFO    Log message is here

or if I needed the time:
01:11.930Z  INFO    Log message is here

One option I looked at was the --output table flag thinking I could then choose which columns I wanted to see, however I could not find any documentation for this.
Is there a way to customise the output of these log messages?
Thanks.

If you’re using CloudWatch Logs Live Tail within the AWS Console, there’s no direct built-in option to customize the display by hiding the log ID or timestamp. However, if you are using the CLI you can print your full log
aws logs start-live-tail --log-group-identifiers <your-log-group-arn-without-the :* at the end> --mode print-only

then keep just the interested levels for you using the awk and format the output as you need
aws logs start-live-tail --log-group-identifiers <your-log-group-arn-without-the :* at the end> --mode print-only | awk '{print $3, $4, $5}' 

--output does not effect the start-live-tail, as it's stream log in real time, so it bypasses the usual CLI output formatting.
